# My C++ hello world program fails to compile in Atom IDE using the Build script

Tags: c++

so, for some background: I've been trying to get the build package in the atom IDE (since apparently, atom doesn't have a run or build button, what a waste should I say) to work for a while now, the details I don't want to bore you with, anyways I have everything up my sleeve but it all came out inconclusive.

---

so here's my code:

```
<#include <iostream>>
using namespace std;

int() {
  cout << "hello world"
  return 0;
}
```

I used this code to test the build package in the atom IDE to see if it could compile c++ code but I got an error:

```
   " no eligible build target found "
```

i clicked on the show stack trace button and this displayed:

```
   "No eligible build target.: No configuration to build this project exists.
at file///C:/Users/Administrator/.atom/packages/build/lib/build.js:113:15"
```

anyways, after all this i still have a question:

*- why is this happening to me, and what can I do to fix this?*

**if you find a way to fix this then don't be afraid to answer, if you don't, do some research, hopefully it should help people who are answering this question**

Comment: 1st of all you should fix the typos in your hello world example.

Comment: _is my code wrong in some way?_ Yes. `<#include <iostream>>` should be `#include <iostream>`. `int() {` should be `int main() {`.

Comment: FYI: [Reddit: I'm trying to run C++ with Atom and I'm getting this error message when I try to run code.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atom/comments/etqz0r/im_trying_to_run_c_with_atom_and_im_getting_this/), [Reddit: How to run C/C++ in atom?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Atom/comments/cehc43/how_to_run_cc_in_atom/)

Comment: If I remember it right, "Script" only work with unix environments. I use [gpp-compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler)

Comment: I'm using the build package, not script

Comment: also, gpp compiler looks like a horribly hacky kinda package, i wanna just download and go on with my life

Answer (score 2):

you need a semicolon after your cout statement
and your main function needs to be defined as main

```
int main() {
  cout << "hello world";
  return 0;
}
```